# How to change network card

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I have a server which has a network card onboard and one extra:

```
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
enp0s31f6  1500 0     71399    401      0 0        103940      0      0      0 BMRU
enp2s0     1500 0         0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
lo        65536 0      1530      0      0 0          1530      0      0      0 LRU
```

I encounter a lot of errors with the onboard card so I just want to swicht it of and use the external card -> enp2s0

Poor man's approach:

1. I have switched off the onboard card in the bios
2. shutdown the server
3. swapped the networkcable (now plugged in enp2s0
4. restart the server

When I now start a client requesting an IP for the DHCP server running on the above mentioned server than I get after a while the message that no IP could be retrieved. When I undo my changes, the IP is provided.

So there must be a relation between DHCP server an the new interface. But I do not find it. A grep on etc/ for the old interface does show only an entry in etc/iftab, I have commended that out, rebooted but still no success.

I fear that I have not enough understanding how things relate to each other.

So which further steps to I need to take to make dhcp work? Most likely this is not an dhcp issues but an network config issue?

Comment: What do you have set for `INTERFACES=` in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`?

Comment: I have there  INTERFACES=""

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server as it looks like you might need to set your other card in the interfaces part so that the server knows which card it is going to use.  Also, make sure that you set the IP address accordingly for other interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since I there was no direct link in the dhcp configurations further research resulted in a static IP config for the server:

```
[connection]
interface-name=enp0s31f6


[ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=90:1B:0E:xx:xx:xx
```

Having that changed all problems where solved. This finally was the indirect link from netwotk/iface to dhcp server not providing an IP